# CollectionView content under navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, iphone-x

I **want** the content of the collectionView to start from the very top of the screen (top of status bar) because I have transparent navigation bar, I want to avoid magic numbers and it should work with iPhone X and other iPhones.

What I have tried ?

`collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

but it's not an elegant solution and it's not correct for iPhone X the inset needs to be increased

Any clean solution ?

Target iOS 10 and 11

Comment: set UICollectionView top 0 with Main View. no need to set contentInset.

Answer (score 13):

Add this in the `UIViewController` containing the `UICollectionView` to prevent the collection view to go under the navigation bar. E.g. in the `viewDidLoad` method:

**Swift 4**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.bottom
```

You can even set `edgesForExtendedLayout = []` to prevent the collection view to go under UITabBars too.

Comment: This one worked for me, but additionally I had to use -64 (nav bar + status bar) as a value for constraint on collection view using top Safe Area.

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 5**
Try this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

and from the IB Size Inspector Tab set "content Insets" to "Never".

Answer (score 3):

If your collection view is already fullscreen you should also set `collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using interface builder, this can be easily done by setting the top space constraint of the collection view to have 0 `constant` from the `superview` and **not** the `safe area`.

```
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Consider that this approach will work on iOS11, but will crash on iOS10. This is because I'm still using safe area for leading and trailing, safe area is not available in iOS10. Using Xcode 9 and interface builder you get a free conversion from safe area to layout guides.

Comment: is it possible with code ? I'm using `SnapKit` but I can use native code layout system

Comment: I never used snapkit, but it could be something like that using auto layout API, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this property on your viewcontroller containing the collectionview

> self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

Answer (score 0):

this line of code worked for me

collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never